# What does "boi" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand this meme. What does "boi" mean in this context?

[image]

Comment: It's a currently fashionable way to spell "boy". It means, on its surface, "boy". The rest of the meme implies "exasperation and superciliousness, pending condescending lesson". In other words ***Boy***, *imma bout to explain you somethin'* (substitute *learn* in the ergative sense for *explain* if you like). In my experience this developed on social media, particularly Twitter, among the POC and SJW community. It's their eye-dialect (kinda) for "authentic speech", "real talk".

Comment: On a related note: the word (and general pattern) has spread on social media outside the POC/SJW community, and now has picked up usage among a broader population, essentially as a cutesy synonym for "guy" (in the "man", "dude", casual/informal-reference-to-male-individual sense). See the recent ["once-in-a-lifetime event of cosmic proportions vs. **1 poofy boi**"](https://i.redd.it/kjydrf80z4hz.jpg) meme commenting on the 2017 August eclipse in NA.

Comment: In the previous comment, when I say "cutsey", I am referring to the recent trend of words like "snek" (*snake*), "doggo" (*dog*), and here "boi" (*boy* => *guy, dude, individual*).

Comment: I just want to point out that this particular meme has an [entry](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/breath-in-boi) on knowyourmeme.com. While the resource is not always to be trusted, it does oftentimes give a plausible explanation of the origin and meaning of such images.

Comment: @DanBron Many of such "meme" images used to come from places like 4chan and Something Awful and then reposted all over the web, though I have not been following the "internet culture" lately to claim it's still the predominant source of new "memes".

Comment: @undercat Memes are created by and on all social media platforms now. The ur-memers are indeed 4chan and slightly later SA, but these days it's Reddit, Tumblr, Twitter, FB, Imgur and an uncountable host more. KYM exists to help track down he original source of memes, but I think the Internet is going to erase the concept of "attribution" eventually. Today the best way to get a bead on a new meme, if it's not documented already, is to interpret the tone. If it's SJW-y, Tumblr and Twitter are good bets. If more rightwing, Reddit or maybe YT. If eye-bleachingly horrifying, good old 4han is around

Comment: @DanBron While I agree on this rule of thumb in general, attributing Internet jokes based on their tone, quality and the issues they deal with (if any) seems like something that will only reinforce social media stereotypes. We must never forget that in the end, all those images are created by unique individuals and not the websites that they frequent.

Comment: @undercat Yes, I agree. I didn't mean use meme characteristics to attribute them, but instead as a clue to kick off an investigation to their origins. The first fingerprint which may lead to the "culprit". But I also think as the Internet gets bigger, deeper, and faster, tracking down the actually originator of a work will get harder and harder. Even today, people go through the additional step of cutting out artists' watermarks before sharing them, for example. In other words: "[You made this? I made this.](http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1079173-i-made-this)".

Comment: @DanBron I like your answer. Why put it as a comment instead of an actual answer?

Comment: Update: [NPR actually published an article](http://www.npr.org/sections/alltechconsidered/2017/04/23/524514526/dogs-are-doggos-an-internet-language-built-around-love-for-the-puppers) on the "cutesy" language I mentioned earlier, and it specifically calls out *boi* as having entered that lexicon as well (as in [this FB post](https://www.facebook.com/groups/dogspotting/permalink/10155334823339467/) it links to). But remember this is a different and newer usage than your meme's "condescending *boi*".

Comment: Related question: [What is the etymology of "fanboi"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51493/what-is-the-etymology-of-fanboi)

Comment: The [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=boi) might help, or might not.

Answer (score 1):

The word "boi" is part of the modern vernacular.  It can mean many things depending on the audience or speaker, but it is often accompanied by a hand gesture similar to the second image in the meme above.

The term is used as an exclamation, a term of derision, or as a variant of the word boy, adopted by a special interest community.

Answer (score 0):

When used it means "seriously" or "are you kidding me" people say it when someone else does something that they think is stupid

Comment: Do you have a reference? There's much more information in comments than you've added here.

Comment: What's an acceptable reference?  This was (at the time) the bleeding edge of internet colloqualisms, nobody's writing articles about it, and this answer is actually correct.  +1 for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

As a fan of memes, I can help.

When someone says 'boi', they usually say it instead of something like 'Fam, are you kidding me?'. It's meant to imply severe disbelief at something which someone has said and is frequently accompanied by hand gestures (as shown in the meme).